# send old log files by its date from logstash to a elasticsearch index by log file date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have some old log files (one file per day).
By default, the timestamp of the index is the date of the creation of the index.
I am trying to create an index for each of these log file and I want the timestamp of the index corresponding to each log file to be the same as the one defined by the name of the file. consider that these log files proccessed by logstash:
A sample of log line :
2021-10-27 09:13:16,225 INFO adminPortal.aspect.RequestLoggerAspect
[http-nio-3030-exec-4]
my logstash conf :

```
grok {
 match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-% 
 {MONTHDAY} 
%{TIME}) %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{JAVACLASS:className} \[(?<threadname> 
 [A- 
 Za-z0-9_-]+)\] %{GREEDYDATA:API_request_and_response}" }
  }
        date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
  target => "@timestamp"
  }
   }
 output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "admins-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }'
```

Comment: Did you try to get file name with grok? `grok { match => [ "path", "/(?<filename>[^/]+).log" ] }`. After this you can use file name on output. `index => "%{filename}"`

Comment: do you mean you want the old log entries to go into indices that use dates that match the dates in those logs? if so then you need to use a date filter in your config

Comment: yes ,I used date filter and I have the correct timestamp but it doesnt replace @timestamp
A sample of log line :  
2021-10-27 09:13:16,225 INFO adminPortal.aspect.RequestLoggerAspect [http-nio-3030-exec-4]

Comment: @Mark Walkom
I put the code. Can you help me

Comment: Your date filter is wrong, the miliseconds separator is a comma `,` and not dot `.`, try to change the date filter to `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS`

Comment: thanx so much sir.the solution is working .@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123206/leandrojmp